# ASP.NET Core Get different JSON data from an injected service based on the user's language

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-core, service

I'm working on a website and I need to display data from a JSON file.

Now the thing is, I need to get this data from an injected singleton service based on the user's language.

It should look something like that:

```cs
// Servies
services.AddSingleton<JsonLocalizationService>();

// Razor Page
@inject JsonLocalizationService

@JsonLocalizationService["nested"]["item"]

// file.en.json
{
  "nested": {
    "item": "Hello"
  }
}

// file.ru.json
{
  "nested": {
    "item": "Привет"
  }
}
```

The equivalent of the above code if I was using Shared Localization Service:

```
// Service
  public class CommonResources
{

}  

public class CommonLocalizationService
    {

        private readonly IStringLocalizer _localizer;
        public CommonLocalizationService(IStringLocalizerFactory factory)
        {
            var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(typeof(CommonResources).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName);

            _localizer = factory.Create(nameof(CommonResources), assemblyName.Name);
        }

        public string Get(string key)
        {
            return _localizer.GetString(key);
        }
    }

services.AddSingleton<CommonLocalizationService>();

// Razor page
@inject CommonLocalizationService Localizer

@Localizer.Get("key") // This automatically gets the key in the localized file.
```

But the example above doesn't work with JSON and nesting.

The service needs to provide the appropriate file based on the user's language. (if English provide `file.en.json` if Russian provide `file.ru.json`)

How can I accomplish that?

I've looked into the source code of asp.net core but I didn't see where they were checking the language to switch between the files.

Comment: You can check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0#make-the-apps-content-localizable-2), on the sever side, we could use the IStringLocalizer and IStringLocalizer<T>  to make the content localizable, on the client side, we could use the IViewLocalizer  service provides localized strings.